# NullPointerException when iterating over ArrayList in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I am displaying a list which contains objects which store message information. The list is loaded through getting the request as such:

```
ArrayList<MessageModel> list = (ArrayList<MessageModel>) request.getAttribute("msgList");
```

I am trying to display information contained in each object as such:

```
for(MessageModel msg : list){
                String messageTo = msg.toAddress;
                String messageSub = msg.messageSubject;
                out.println(messageTo+ " " +messageSub);
            }
```

I am getting a  NullPointerException at the for each statement.

As an aside, I am using this approach to debug as I want to check whether or not I can display the content of the MessageModel object at all. I tried using JSTL forEach tag but I could not access the object attributes.

```
 <c:forEach items="${list}" var="current">
     <li><c:out value="${current.toAddress}"/></li>
 </c:forEach>
```

I set the attribute like this :

```
 ArrayList<MessageModel> list =(ArrayList<MessageModel>) request.getAttribute("msgList");
 pageContext.setAttribute("messages", list);
```

This results in the following error message when run :

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /inbox.jsp (line: 37, column: 12) According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute items does not accept any expressions
```

And intelliJ says that it cannot resolve the variable list.

EDIT :

I forward the request from a servlet that handles user login as follows :

```
 ArrayList<MessageModel> msglist = MessageModel.getRecievedMessages(username);
 request.setAttribute("msgList", msglist);
```

I am trying to pass the ArrayList that contains the message objects and then iterate over the list and display it in the jsp.

Is there a possibility for the jsp itself to get the information ? I have a separate java class which handles the messages with a bunch of helper functions. So can I call the method that retrieves all those messages and display them without explicitly setting a request attribute in the servlet ? Because I will be navigating between other pages in the application.

Sorry if my vocabulary was off, this is the first time I am working with jsp's and servlets.

Comment: how did u set the list in the request scope show that please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `NullPointerException` in the foreach loop is probably due to the `list` variable being `null`. You may check for `list`not being `null` before iterating over it.

Regarding the `JasperException`, can you describe how you forward to the JSP ?

Also, it's probably a typo, but you set an attribute named `messages`, then you iterate over an attribute named `list` in the `<c:foreach>`...

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, I edited the original post with more information.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using creating getter and setter methods to get the class members of MessageModel.

[EL tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info): this article helped me understand how to interface a java class and a jsp.